# Distinct on Excel between 2 Sheets

Tags: excel, formula

i have single file excel with 2 sheets :

-Sheet1
Column A : {1,2,3,4,5}

-Sheet2
Column A : {2,5}

my question is, how to display numbers not in Sheet2 from Sheet1?

so the result numbers is {1,3,4}

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this, the simplest is to use Vlookup all the way down the column of one sheet to determine if the same value exists in the other sheet. (Thus creating a "Difference" flag). You can then use excel filters on the sheet to either keep what matched or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I can demonstrate using two column on a single worksheet. You should have no trouble transcribing this to two worksheets for your own purposes.

As an array formula¹ in D2 (empty or column header label cell above first cell with formula is required),

```
=INDEX(A$1:A$5, MATCH(0, IF(ISNA(MATCH(A$1:A$5, B$1:B$2, 0)), COUNTIF(D$1:D1, A$1:A$5&""), 1), 0))
```

Add error control with the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) and fill down as necessary.

[image: list_unique_not_in_other]

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type the braces in yourself. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Comment: could i do the same thing by different sheets, couldn't i?

Comment: As I stated above, *'You should have no trouble transcribing this to two worksheets for your own purposes.'*